# How to create the name space for a kid's math worksheet? and other issues?

Tags: math-mode

I want my worksheet the name and date to the left above the worksheet's title. I also want to learn what code to use to adjust the spacing. The spacing is a little off and I want the two columns of problems to be symmetrical. This is my code and I was hoping that someone experienced in this type-setting language can assist:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{7th Grade Algebra: Exponents}
\author{Ms. Lampianerani} 
\maketitle
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Name:  & \rule{0.25\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\ 
Date:  & \rule{0.25\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\ 
\end{tabular}

\section{Notes} 
 Simplify the following negative exponent problems. You want to get an answer with   all positive exponents. 

\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}  
\begin{enumerate}

\item $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k^{-5}}$
\item $k^{-5}$ 
\item $a^3 b^{-2}$
\item $c^{-4}d^{4}$ 
\item $(a^2 b^{-7})^{0}$

\end{enumerate}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}  
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{5}

\item $\displaystyle \frac{-45}{5x^{-6}}$
\item $\displaystyle \frac{x^{-8}}{4y^{15}}$ 
\item $\displaystyle \frac{2a^3}{b^{-5}}$ 
\item $\displaystyle \frac{y^{-9}}{x^{-15}}$ 
\item $ - 10y^{-3}$ 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{flushright} 
\end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Are you open to using the `exam` document class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be better off with `exam` class or `exsheets` package. Any how, here is an answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,multicol,eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \makebox(400,55)[lt]{%   %% change 55 for vertical adjustment
      \footnotesize%
      \begin{tabular}{r@{\,}l}
        Name:  & \rule{0.5\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\[.5cm]
        Date:  & \rule{0.5\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\
      \end{tabular}
}}}
\title{7th Grade Algebra: Exponents}
\author{Ms. Lampianerani}
\maketitle
\section{Notes}
 Simplify the following negative exponent problems. You want to get an answer with   all positive exponents.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\dfrac{1}{k^{-5}}$
\item $k^{-5}$
\item $a^3 b^{-2}$
\item $c^{-4}d^{4}$
\item $(a^2 b^{-7})^{0}$
\item $\dfrac{-45}{5x^{-6}}$
\item $\dfrac{x^{-8}}{4y^{15}}$
\item $\dfrac{2a^3}{b^{-5}}$
\item $\dfrac{y^{-9}}{x^{-15}}$
\item $ - 10y^{-3}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want name and date only on first page, use `\AddToShipoutPicture*{%` instead of `\AddToShipoutPicture{%` in the code (note `*`).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is in `\newcommand\Blank...`, but consider using the exam document class for your quizzes.  Note also that `\dfrac` is defined in `amsmath` as a shortcut of sorts for `\displaystyle\frac`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}

\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\Blank[2][.33\linewidth]{%
  % add strut to allow for handwriting
  \rule{0pt}{4ex}%
  % Prompt
  #2\enspace
  % And the actual line
  \makebox[#1]{\hrulefill}}

\title{7th Grade Algebra: Exponents}
\author{Ms.~Lampianerani} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{flushright}
  \Blank{Name:}

  \Blank{Date:}
\end{flushright}

\section{Notes}
Simplify the following negative exponent problems.  You want to get an
answer with all positive exponents.

\begin{questions}
  \begin{multicols}{2} 
    \question $\dfrac{1}{k^{-5}}$
    \question $k^{-5}$ 
    \question $a^3 b^{-2}$
    \question $c^{-4}d^{4}$ 
    \question $(a^2 b^{-7})^{0}$
    \question $\dfrac{-45}{5x^{-6}}$
    \question $\dfrac{x^{-8}}{4y^{15}}$ 
    \question $\dfrac{2a^3}{b^{-5}}$ 
    \question $\dfrac{y^{-9}}{x^{-15}}$ 
    \question $ - 10y^{-3}$ 
  \end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd also put a "tie" (`~`) between `Ms.` and the teacher's last name, since the `.` in `Ms.` is not a sentence-ending punctuation mark.

Comment: @Mico Ah yes.  I'm not used to seeing titles in `\author`.  Edited.